# Javascript onclick with getElementById not working

Tags: php, javascript, html

Simple onclick function to enable an html textbox is not working... nothing happens upon clicking the textbox.  Uses a variable as part of the id.

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function unlock(id)
{
    document.getElementById('strain'+id).disabled=false;
    return false;
}

    </script>


<input id="strain343" type="text" value="54.24" onclick="return unlock(343);" disabled="true" name="strain"></input>
```

Comment: JS belongs in .js files, you should never need to build functional JS with server side code.

Comment: What does the rendered HTML looks like?

Comment: Either your PHP is not generating the JS/HTML you want, or the JS/HTML you are generating doesn't do what you expect. Determine what that is. Then ask a question asking about how to make the PHP generate the JS you want or a question about how to make the JS do what you want. Don't show us PHP and ask us to debug the resulting JavaScript.

Comment: Also, run the HTML through [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/) as there are some errors.

Comment: Gotcha... I edited the post to include only the rendered html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabled inputs don't capture click events.

See [a simplified demo](http://jsbin.com/ilasib/1/edit).

See also [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#enabling-and-disabling-form-controls):

> A form control that is disabled must prevent any click events that are queued on the user interaction task source from being dispatched on the element.

---

You need to rethink your UI to either avoid the element being disabled or to avoid the need for it to be clicked on.

Comment: Beautiful... I couldn't figure this out for the life of me.  I'll try it using readonly instead of disabled... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your input inside another block element; attach the onclick event to that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "click" a disabled input. But click events are captured by parents though.

```
    <div id="strainWrapper" onclick="unlock(343)">
        <input class="strainTB" id="strain343" type="text" value="54.24" disabled="true"></input>
    </div>
    <script>
        function unlock(id) {
            document.getElementById('strain' + id).disabled = false;
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```